# Tableau - Dynamic Parameter Reference

Tags: tableau-api

I have a series of parameters in Tableau corresponding to every month in the coming years. The parameter names are all in the format `Name - YYYY-MM-DD` where `YYYY-MM-DD` is the corresponding beginning of the month. I would like to reference the parameter using the current month value (e.g. `2017-11-01`).

How can I reference a parameter using something like the following:

`["Name "+DATEFUNCTION()]`

where `DATEFUNCTION()` will create the date in the appropriate format. However, this clearly does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing parameter name dynamically is not possible.
 You can either try to implement your logic of pulling data out of parameters as a single calculated field or use a secondary datasource containing Date,Value,DummyLinkToPrimary fields and filter it on date.